# Need help in automatically computing optimal hyper-parameters for a clustering algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, k-means

I have an algorithm that take as input some data (that are continuously arriving) and 3 or 4 parameter values that should be specified by the user. At the and of execution (or periodically during execution) we can evaluate the performance to see if the chosen parameter values were good or not, but the evaluation function is expensive (time and space consuming). There is no way to know *a priori* what are the best matching parameter values, unless we perform many execution and evaluations until we find the parameter values that gives a good results.

Note that even if we try to variate the parameter values to find the best one by executing the algorithm many times on the same data, these values might be not good for another set of data (this is one reason of why I need to adapt them automatically during execution).

EDIT1: Some additional information: the algorithm is supposed to do **online clustering on a continuously arriving data stream.** The parameters are mainly some threshold values or used to compute some adaptive threshold values needed by the algorithm.

EDIT2: Some additional information regarding the desired algorithm: Each time a new data x is given to the algorithm, it will see if x should be assigned to an existing cluster (i.e. adapting an existing cluster representative n), or if a new representative based on x should be created. To do that, each representative has a threshold value, if distance between x and nearest representative is less than the threshold of this representative, then x is assigned to this representative, else a new representative will be created based on x. Now some parameters are involved at this level: I assign a default initial threshold value to each new created representative (this is one parameter); when a new data is assigned to an existing representative (cluster) the threshold of this representative is updated, this is what I actually call "adaptive threshold", its defined by "the mean of distances between the representative and its currently associated data" + param * "the standard deviation of this distances" (param here is another parameter). Then I have some other parameters that influence the final number of representatives, like for example the age beyond which an old representative should be deleted ... So here I gave 3 examples of the parameters used by the algorithm.

**Questions:**

1. Is there any solution to automatically adapt the parameter values during the execution ?
2. Is it better to try to define a function that adapts these parameters and this function depends on a less sensitive parameter(s) ? Any idea is welcome.

Note that my problem is not the clustering algorithm itself; it gives "good results" iif "the good parameter values" are chosen, thus I wanted to know if there anyway to automatically adapt them.

Comment: Could you please give some more context for the parameters? What is the algorithm supposed to do? If you feel that a detailed explanation is unnecessary, just a few sentences could help a lot.

Comment: @penelope the algorithm is supposed to do online clustering on a continuously arriving data stream. The parameters are mainly some threshold values or used to compute some adaptive threshold values needed by the algorithm.

Comment: It would help if you provided a small example (numeric or formulation) of your problem, and some sample of the incoming data and examples of the user-input parameters. Also, if you elaborate on what you mean by 'adpative threshold values' that would help.

Comment: @user995434 I have taken the liberty of editing your question to better reflect what you are looking for. Feel free to change/modify if I altered your original intent. Also, there are lots of SO questions on cluster-analysis and k-means, which are pertinent to your need.

Comment: Sounds like you are doing online k-means. Did you see if existing literature such as "Efficient online spherical k-means clustering" does answer your question already?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse this is different from the online k-means. My algorithm doesn't need to know what is the number of clusters (K) and the initialisation of each representative. It instead starts from 0 representative and create them incrementally. Nevertheless, my problem isn't the clustering algorithm itself, it gives "good results" iif "the good parameter values" are chosen, thus I wanted to know if there anyway to automatically adapt them.

Comment: I believe there are also online k-means variations that do not require k to be chosen beforehand, but that adapt k.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse if you find an online k-means that do not require k to be chosen beforehand but that adapt it incrementally, let me know. I've not yet found such a k-means.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is to perturb these parameters slightly (e.g. by adding a vector with Gaussian distributed noise to it) each time. Then you perform the clustering with the old and the new parameters simultaneously. If the new parameters give better results you use them from now on. You can then go further and try to adapt the noise strength for each component so that you perturb those parameters less that are already very good.

That's similar to having a simple 1+1 [evolution strategy](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Evolution_Strategies) as optimizer for your parameters. A typical way to update your noise strengths (also called mutation strength) would be to use sigma self-adaptation.

Comment: This seems to be a good way to deal with the problem. However, I didn't well understood how do you perturb the parameters by adding noise to them ? Nevertheless, I'll read the article in the link you provided, this sounds good for my problem, I didn't heard about the Evolution Strategies before.

Comment: How to perturb the parameters? Assume you have your parameter vector p, then you calculate the perturbed vector p_prime = p + n with n being a vector where each component is being independently sampled from a normal distribution, e.g. N(0, sigma).